# how to access the list inside a list in c++?

Tags: c++

Okay, so I first started learning C# and now I am learning C++ so I'm kind of new to it.
In C#, when I wanted to access the list inside a list, I would simply use nested for-each loops.

Now since in C++ I don't know how to use a for-each loop, I tried to access the nested list with for loops.

Here is my code:

```
int main

{      
    list<list<char *> > moves; 

    list<char *> pointers;

    list<list<char> > undoValues;
    list<char> undoValue;

    for(list<list<char *> >::iterator outer=moves.begin();outer!=moves.end();outer++)
    {
        for(list<char *>::iterator inner=outer.begin();inner!=outer.end();inner++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I get 2 errors:

```
error 'struct std::_List_iterator<std::list<char*>,std::allocator<char *> > >' has no member named begin

error 'struct std::_List_iterator<std::list<char*>,std::allocator<char *> > >' has no member named end
```

How can I access the nested list?

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference the iterators to get to the element. You can either use `*` or `->`:

```
for(list<char *>::iterator inner=outer->begin();inner!=outer->end();inner++)
```

or

```
for(list<char *>::iterator inner=(*outer).begin();inner!=(*outer).end();inner++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use (*outer) to get what the iterator is pointing to:

```
list<char *> pointers;

list<list<char> > undoValues;
list<char> undoValue;
for(list<list<char *> >::iterator outer=moves.begin();outer!=moves.end();outer++)
{
    for(list<char *>::iterator inner=(*outer).begin();inner!=(*outer).end();inner++)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(list<list<char *> >::iterator outer=moves.begin();outer!=moves.end();outer++)
    for(list<char *>::iterator inner=outer->begin();inner!=outer->end();inner++)
```

Answer (score 0):

To access members of the object an iterator refers to, you need indirection; so the `begin()` member of the `outer` list is `outer->begin()`, not `outer.begin()`. Likewise for `end()`.